# indeterminate checkbox in virtual-dom hyperscript

Tags: javascript, virtual-dom

How do I create an indeterminate checkbox in virtual hyperscript?

```
h('input', {
  type: 'checkbox', 
  checked: data.state === 'checked', 
  indeterminate: data.state === 'indeterminate'
})
```

will not work, as `indeterminate` is a property not an attribute.